# javascript regex for at least x numeric characters

Tags: javascript, regex

a regex to show that there are at least 10 numeric characters in a string.

There can be more than 10, but not less.
There can be any number of other characters in at random places, separating the numbers.

Example Data:

```
(123) 456-7890
123-456-7890 ext 41
1234567890
etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making sure at lest 10 digits are there use this regex:

```
/^(\D*\d){10}/
```

**Code:**

```
var valid = /^(\D*\d){10}/.test(str);
```

**TESTING:**

```
console.log(/^(\D*\d){10}/.test('123-456-7890 ext 41')); // true
console.log(/^(\D*\d){10}/.test('123-456-789')); // false
```

**Explanation:**

```
^ assert position at start of the string
1st Capturing group (\D*\d){10}
Quantifier: Exactly 10 times
Note: A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration.
Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a 
non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data
\D* match any character that's not a digit [^0-9]
Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible
\d match a digit [0-9]
```

Comment: I hate regexps.  Even though I've used them for who knows how many years, it's not immediately 100% obvious how that works.

Comment: I added some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably simplest to just get rid of all the non-numeric characters and count what's left:

```
var valid = input.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').length >= 10
```

NB: `.replace` doesn't modify the original string.

Answer (score 1):

```
(\d\D*){10}
```

A digit followed by any number of non-digits, ten times.